# Does a multidimensional Soft Pot Exist?

Tags: analog, components, potentiometer, input

I have no idea if this exists, but I'm looking for a soft pot/ribbon sensor that would function like a laptop trackpad (ie. giving a resistance value for the X position of the finger on the pad and a resistance value for the Y). I don't really want to need to have any sort of microcontroller associated with it as this is for an analog synthesizer where latency is sort of the enemy.

The component would function as a control interface for the synthesizer, the X axis for example possibly controlling pitch, with the Y controlling modulation. If this doesn't exist, can anyone point me in the direction of something that may serve a similar purpose?

Comment: Google “joystick” and see if one of those would work for you?

Comment: This site discourages "shopping" type questions. I suggest that you look at www.piclist.com (do NOT be put off by the arcane presentation or the PIC in the name) then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist and join the mailing list and say hello. It's likely that at least one list member is a guru in your area of interest. And while the list is very quiet these days there are people there who know almost everything (collectively) like here BUT unlike here you are allowed to discuss anything conversationally. Some members of this group are also PICList members (myself included).

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a resistive touch screen membrane,

A long time ago a company called "Koala" did a [resistive digitiser pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KoalaPad) for "Apple ][" PCs and other 8-bit machines. but these days your best bet is probably to re-purpose a resistive touch-screen digitiser.